# Error when running specs: Poltergeist detected another element with CSS selector

Tags: capybara, activeadmin, poltergeist

I added activeadmin in my Gemfile.

I ran:

```
rails g active_admin:install Admin User
rake db:migrate
```

Then I ran:

```
bundle exec rake test:integrations
```

and I got this error:

```
Capybara::Poltergeist::ClickFailed:
Click at co-ordinates [330.5, 714] failed. Poltergeist detected another element 
with CSS selector 'html body div#ui-datepicker-div.ui-datepicker.ui-widget.ui-widget-content.ui-helper-clearfix.ui-corner-all div.ui-datepicker-header.ui-widget-header.ui-helper-clearfix.ui-corner-all div.ui-datepicker-title span.ui-datepicker-month' 
at this position. It may be overlapping the element you are trying to click.
```

I tried excluding the activeadmin js and css as recommended in [this post](http://mrdanadams.com/2011/exclude-active-admin-js-css-rails/#.UnpVQY3QGbK), but I still get the error.

Does anyone have any ideas of how to solve this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I am assuming the message is from a failing capybara step. I ran into this issue today when using the following against an ajax form:

```
find('some-css').click()
```

Unfortunately on occasion it was returning the very frustrating overlapping css error. What I did was to use this method instead:

```
find('some-css').trigger('click')
```

And hey presto works every time :)

Hope this helps.

Comment: This answer does fix the problem, but I think a more interesting question is why Poltergeist cares about overlapping elements. HTML elements overlap all the time, what gives in this case to raise the exception?!

Comment: I agree, this answer provides a work-around fix to get past this. I guess join the troops and log an issue with phantomjs.

Comment: @mecampbellsoup if I understand correctly the message could be clearer: it's telling you not just that the elements overlap, but that the overlapping element is blocking you from clicking the element you intended to click.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this bug because I tested a hover and then needed to click on the link underneath the tooltip. The solution was to add `page.find('.sp-logo').hover` before `click_link` to get the tooltip out of the way.

Answer (score 1):

I had another bug where `find_link` on Chrome and Poltergeist could not click an A tag with an EM tag and some text inside of it, although it worked fine in Firefox and rack_test. The solution was to replace `click_link(link)` with `find('a em', text: link).click`. Unfortunately, this doesn't work on rack_test, resulting in this hack:

```
When /^I click the emphasized text "([^\"]*)"$/ do |link|
  if Capybara.current_driver == :rack_test
    click_link(link)
  else
    find('a em', text: link).click
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, wanted to test a second click - forgot about a modal showing after the first click. Found it after reading the massive CSS selector to the end.

```
detected another element with CSS selector
'html.js...alotofotherclasses...div.sweet-alert.show-sweet-alert.visible'
```

Solved it by dismissing it - so basically - just read the message carefully.

```
click_button I18n.t('mail_form.submit')
expect(page).to have_content I18n.t('mail_form.flash.submitted')
click_button I18n.t('alert.ok')
```