# Capybara::Poltergeist::MouseEventFailed after Haml update (4.0.7 => 5.0.2) [RAILS]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, haml

Hi we are currently updating our HAML file from version `4.0.7` to `5.0.2`. After the update a lot of cucumber tests break saying;

```
Firing a click at co-ordinates [422.5, 414] failed. 
Poltergeist detected another element with CSS selector 'html.javascript body div.ui-widget-overlay.ui-front' at this position. 
It may be overlapping the element you are trying to interact with. 
If you don't care about overlapping elements, try using node.trigger('click'). 
(Capybara::Poltergeist::MouseEventFailed)
```

**It breaks at the parts where i'm using interpolation in i18n texts like this:**

```
You_are_on_a_device: You are on a %{type} device
```

And in the view im using something like this:

```
%p.dialog{'data-attribute' => t('you_are_on_a_device', type: '<a href="http://mywebsite.nl/type">small</a>').html_safe, hidden: true}
```

I can't seem to find the breaking change from the [Haml Changelog](https://github.com/haml/haml/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

Does anybody know whats causing this and what i can do to fix this?

Comment: I have a few questions in order to be able to help you with debugging:
 1. When you run the server in development, the `data-attribute` is set correctly in the generated view?  2. The output of `I18n.t('you_are_on_a_device', type: 'small')` in rails console is correct?  3. the `"data-attribute"` key without quotation marks is a typo?

Comment: 1. data-attribute is set correctly but breaks at the 'type' interpolation of the i18n text.
2. the ouput is correct in the console.
3. Yeah that's a typo sorry, fixed it in the OP.

Comment: note: i also have to mention that the type value in the interpolation has html in it. (also added to post now).

Comment: I don't know if it could be useful: https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist/issues/520 It seems that in another scenario, some people solved the same exception raised by your test forcing another window size

Comment: Can you post your actual haml? I had a similar situation happen to me because of a slight error in the haml which seemed undetectable, but a second set of eyes might catch it!

Comment: I hope this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18765459/error-when-running-specs-poltergeist-detected-another-element-with-css-selector

Comment: @luissimo I think that this issue is not related to the haml upgrade. Did you upgrade capybara or poltergeist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved:**

The solution was to put the data attributes value in an interpolated string like this:

```
%p.dialog{'data-attribute' => "#{t('you_are_on_a_device', type: '<a href="http://mywebsite.nl/type">small</a>').html_safe}", hidden: true}
```

and in my **config/initializers/haml.rb**

```
Haml::Template.options[:escape_html] = false
```

It was because of the html escaping that has become standard in HAML 5.0.0, where it wasn't in HAML 4.0.7

Answer (score 0):

Disabling html escaping is NOT a good practice because it makes your app prone to XSS attacks. For example, when an attacker type in their username `<script>alert('Vasya')</script>` other users will see an alert every time Vasya's name will appear on the page. Try the following code:

```
%p= "<script>alert('Vasya')</script>"
```

I installed haml `5.0.2` in a fresh rails project (rails `4.2.6`) and I tried to render the following page:

```
%h1 HAML

%p.dialog{'data-attribute' => t('you_are_on_a_device', type: '<a href="http://mywebsite.nl/type">small</a>').html_safe, hidden: true}

%p.dialog{'data-attribute' => "#{t('you_are_on_a_device', type: '<a href="http://mywebsite.nl/type">small</a>').html_safe}", hidden: true}
```

I don't see any differences in the rendered `p` tags (I've tried both `escape_html` `true` and `false`):

```
<h1>HAML</h1>
<p class="dialog" data-attribute="You are on a <a href=&quot;http://mywebsite.nl/type&quot;>small</a> device" hidden=""></p>
<p class="dialog" data-attribute="You are on a <a href=&quot;http://mywebsite.nl/type&quot;>small</a> device" hidden=""></p>
```

I guess that the `Failed to click on element` issue is caused by other reason, maybe you upgraded capybara or capybara-related gem while upgrading haml

Also it is a good practice to render data-attributes using hash notation:

```
%p.dialog{data: { attribute: t('you_are_on_a_device', type: '<ahref="http://mywebsite.nl/type">small</a>').html_safe }, hidden: true}
```

See more detailed documentation on the haml data attributes [here](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#html5-custom-data-attributes)